# sqlalchemy proper way of using connection

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

This is basically the skeleton of what I am using for executing sql statements

```
engine = "engine_conn_here"


with engine.connect() as connection:
    with connection.begin() as transaction:
        try:
            merge_sql_string = """MERGE SQL QUERY COMMAND HERE"""
            connection.execute(text(merge_sql_string))
            connection.execute(text("DROP TMP_TABLE ..."))
        except:
            transaction.rollback()
            raise
        else:
            transaction.commit()
```

This works fine but just want to check if there is a better way or gotchas that I might missed.

Comment: You should definetely replace `connection.execute` with `transaction.execute`

Comment: @sudden_appearance can you explain why?

Comment: Usually you create a connection to the DB, then from that you create a cursor (U assume that transaction acts as a cursor), and you use the cursor to execute queries, not the connection.

Comment: Why not just [with engne.begin() as conn:](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#connect-and-begin-once-from-the-engine)?